# Can not find webpack.config.js or webpack.config.vendor.js in ASP.NET Core 2.1 SPA Template

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I started the project with dotnet core 2.1 spa template which had angular 5. I was trying to add ng2-toasty to the client app and then i realized the webpack.config.* files were missing from the project.

Here is the Git repo of the project: https://github.com/peeyalk/Vega

Now how do i add ng2-toasty?

Comment: The 2.1 Angular template uses the Angular CLI, so there are no exposed webpack.config.* files ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)). It does still use Webpack under the hood, but the Angular CLI [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib) explain that you can just `npm install` and then `import`.

Answer (score 0):

`ABP` has `tToastr`, i think it will work for you.

Here is the documentation:

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Javascript-API/Notification

If you're using `Angular CLI` be sure to import the css

```
styles: [
 "node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css"
]
```